# In Script#, how can one get a named field from a form?

Tags: c#, script#

Consider this HTML:

```
<form id="MyForm">
    <input name="Input1"/>
</form>
```

In Script# I do this:

```
FormElement form = Document.GetElementById("MyForm");
```

How do I get Input1 from form?

I know I can do something like this:

```
InputElement input1 = (InputElement)Script.Literal("form.Input1");
```

Just wondering if there's a proper way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a better way to do it:

Create a class to represent the form...

```
[Imported]
public class MyForm
{
    public InputElement Input1;
}
```

Typecast the form to MyForm:

```
form = (MyForm)(Object)Document.GetElementById("MyForm");
```

And then I can access Input1 like such:

```
Script.Alert(form.Input1.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your html looks like this:

```
<form id="MyForm">
    <input id="Input1"/>
</form>
```

Note that I change the "name" by the "id" attribute in the input field.

In Script# you can access it using the following,

```
InputElement input1 = Document.GetElementById("Input1").As<InputElement>();
```

You can also use the popular jquery javascript library (wich has an excelent script# import library) to select dom elements in a more flexible way.